# Применение атомарных операций

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь произвести запись информации в `текстовый файл` и в `вектор`, далее *отсортировать вектор* , и попросить вводить информацию снова и так далее до того момента,когда мне нужно остановиться.

Подскажите , пожалуйста, как сделать так,чтобы попросить ввести информацию снова, так как первый раз: ввод и сортировка происходит, как нужно и программа **завершается**.

Думаю , что нужен какой-то цикл, но не знаю, как правильно сделать это...

**STring.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>



class STring
{

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:

    STring(){}
    void Recording();
    void SortVec();

};
```

**STring.cpp:**

```
#include "STring.h"

std::atomic<bool> data_ready(false);

void STring::Recording()
{
    //while (1)
    //{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        std::string fileName;
        std::string str;
        //std::vector<std::string> vec;
        //std::cout << "Input file name: ";
        //std::cin >> fileName;
        std::ofstream out("1.txt", std::ios_base::app);


        std::cout << "Input smth: ";
        while (std::cin >> str)
        {
            out << str;
            vec.push_back(str);
        }
        data_ready = true;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    //}

}

void STring::SortVec()
{
    //while (1) 
    //{
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        while (!data_ready.load())
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        }

        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        for (auto i : vec)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }

    //}

}
```

**Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "STring.h"
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    STring w;

    std::thread Write(&STring::Recording,&w);
    std::thread Sort(&STring::SortVec, &w);

    Sort.join();
    Write.join();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*Результат:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?:

```
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        STring w;

        std::thread Write(&STring::Recording,&w);
        std::thread Sort(&STring::SortVec, &w);

        Sort.join();
        Write.join();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```